# Add signal handler in ECMAscript for just created item

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I want to create `MenuItem` dynamically and add `onTriggered` callback for it.

```
var m = backContextMenu.insertItem(0,text) 

m.onTriggered = ..? //function(x) { console.log('asd') }
```

It gives me error `Cannot assign to read-only property "onTriggered"`. What can I do? Maybe I should create my menu using  `Qt.createQmlObject('qml code...')`? Or maybe I should create `MenuItem` template declaratively and clone this object somehow?

P.S. I use `MenuItem` from `QtQuick.Controls` in Qt 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Connections QML item to create dynamic connections using createQmlObject function :

```
var item = menuContext.insertItem(0, "menu item")
Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.0;Connections{onTriggered:foo()}",item)
```

Simply, you can create also direct connection :

```
item.onTriggered.connect(foo)
```

(MenuItem is necessarily Qt Quick 2 and Qt 5.1)

Comment: Do you recommend to generate `id` for my menu item, generate code above with suitable `onTriggered` body and evaluate it using `Qt.createQmlObject`?
I ask because I don't understand how to use a piece of code above for multiple targets

Comment: Also, I have read that it is impossible to assign id: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6986

Comment: Yes, but it's not necessary to generate id. You are in JS function, then you must create Connections object using createQmlObject. But in fact, you can directly create connection from object. First message updated

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky to find [another way](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-menu.html#items-prop) to add Menu items dynamically: via Instantiator.

```
Menu {
    id: recentFilesMenu

    Instantiator {
        model: recentFilesModel
        MenuItem {
            text: model.fileName
        }
        onObjectAdded: recentFilesMenu.insertItem(index, object)
        onObjectRemoved: recentFilesMenu.removeItem(object)
    }

    MenuSeparator {
        visible: recentFilesModel.count > 0
    }

    MenuItem {
        text: "Clear menu"
        enabled: recentFilesModel.count > 0
        onTriggered: recentFilesModel.clear()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code will explain everything:

```
    Menu {
        id: suggestionsMenu
        property var suggestions: []

        Instantiator {
            model: suggestionsMenu.suggestions
            onObjectAdded: suggestionsMenu.insertItem(index, object)
            onObjectRemoved: suggestionsMenu.removeItem(object)
            delegate: MenuItem {
                text: suggestionsMenu.suggestions[index]
                onTriggered: {
                    console.log(index + " : " + suggestionsMenu.suggestions[index])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in code you only need to call such 3 lines:

```
onShowSuggestions: {
   console.log("Showing suggestions")
   console.log(suggestions)

   suggestionsMenu.clear()
   suggestionsMenu.suggestions = []
   suggestionsMenu.suggestions = suggestions
   suggestionsMenu.popup()
}
```

Links:

[Menu QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html#items-prop)

[Instantiator QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html)

[Article #1](http://imaginativethinking.ca/populate-menu-model-qtquick/)